# How to fix paths in the python code using setuptools to build a portable package?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, easy-install

I am porting a python library across different Linux and BSD distros
This library is packaged using setuptools.

The problem is that the code makes a reference to other files in the system, e.g.:

```
/bin/my-cmd
/etc/default/my-config.cfg
```

But depending on the Linux or BSD distro, the paths are different, e.g.:

```
/usr/local/bin/my-cmd
/etc/my-config.cfg
```

So I would like to know if there is a way to write a pre-install script in setup.py to fix the paths (for prefix and configuration files), so I can make my package portable.

I would like to be able to write in the source code some pattern, e.g.:

```
%%PREFIX%%/bin/my-cmd
```

And replace the pattern `%%PREFIX%%` in setup.py just before it installs the package, is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this in build time, we can add a custom build step in setup.py, iterate through all the python files in the project and replace the patterns, but the best solution I found is to fix the paths in runtime using global variables:

In my `__init__.py` I have:

```
import platform

if platform.system() == 'FreeBSD':
    PREFIX = '/usr/local'
else:
    PREFIX = ''
```

Then I can reference the file locations by using:

```
my_cmd_path = PREFIX + '/bin/my-cmd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it will help you. `__file__` will get the current position.

```
import os

os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'bin/my-cmd')
```

Comment: but can I add this anywhere in the setup.py code? Or setup.py have a special place to put these kind of scripts? Also, how can I retrieve the prefix or the operating system where the package is being installed so I can know which path to replace?

Comment: where is your setup.py located in ?  'bin/my-cmd' ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. The setup.py is part of this project: https://github.com/helen-fornazier/compute-image-packages/tree/development

Comment: setup.py and 'my-cmd' are located in the same directory right ?

Comment: No, setup.py is located in the folder where I did a git clone (any folder), and my-cmd is a command from the system, as "ifconfig" for example, the code calls /bin/ifconfig, but in some systems it could be at /usr/local/bin/ifconfig or /sbin/ifconfig

Comment: I just found out that I can add a custom code using cmdclass in setup.py https://blog.niteoweb.com/setuptools-run-custom-code-in-setup-py/
Maybe I can use this to replace the paths. I am just not sure how can I retrieve the prefix given by --prefix

Comment: I just want to replace the paths according to the the system (if it is a Debian, then use **/bin/my-cmd**, if it is a FreeBSD, then use **/usr/local/bin/my-cmd** instead. I was hoping setup.py to have an automated tool for that (as I can specify the installation prefix), but if it doesn't, then I can implement this functionality by running a custom code in the setup.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149406/discussion-between-simplans-and-lilas).